# Does Java bytecode include "processor instruction information"?

Tags: java, bytecode

Does Java byte code include "processor instruction information"?

[DO-178C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DO-178C) Table A-6 "Testing of Outputs of Integration Process" states that the  “Executable Object Code shall...”, where DO-178 defines object code as the following: “A low-level representation of the computer program not usually in a form directly usable by the target computer but in a form which includes **relocation** information in addition to the processor instruction information.”

Thus, I'm curious if Java bytecode would fit the DO-178C definition of "object code".

I'm not asking, as has been asked numerous times, the difference between byte code and object - I'm specifically interested in if the Java bytecode contains "processor instruction information".

Thanks a ton for your time and any feedback and insights.

According to Oracle: "JIT compilation of the byte code into native machine code has to occur before a method executes"  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15058/underst_jit.htm  I guess that means the native machine processor instruction was lacking prior to this point.  Based on this it seems that "no" the Java bytecode does not include the native machine processor instructions which are present in object code that comes out of a C compiler.

Moreover, Wikipedia (as much as it can be trusted) states: "Bytecode is not the machine code for any particular computer" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation  Thus again, this seems to indicate that Java bytecode lacks the "processor instruction information" that is present within C object code.

Comment: Java byte codes *are* processor instructions—only for a different processor (usually). I would say yes, byte code is object code.

Comment: That definition of object code describes bytecode pretty well.

Comment: Doesn't the JVM include the "processor instruction information" and the byte code intentionally avoid inclusion of "processor instruction information"?

Comment: I would guess that it isn't and that most of these answers are wrong. You should check the rest of the document for a definition of 'Processor Instruction' but the bit you've quoted seems to imply it's something that can be 'run directly on the hardware'. In most cases, Java bytecode is not run directly on hardware.

Comment: @pvg: unfortunately DO-178C does not provide their definition of "processor instruction".

Comment: My guess is that they mean http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/an_introduction_to_gcc/gccintro_14.html / http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/gcc-linking/ kind of non-executable object file which contains instructions for the physical processor but is not yet fully executable since the linker step isn't done. That also explains the "relocation information" which you cut out in your question.

Comment: @zapl is right and the omission of 'relocation information' is critical, I have no idea why you dropped it from a question that revolves around very specific definitions. In the context of these definitions, no Java bytecode is not object code

Comment: @pvg (& zapl)- no idea why I dropped either...evidently my transposition skills failed...sorry

Comment: All, Sorry.  I was hoping this would be simple as yes or no.  The implications are that Java will or will not be able to be used in DO-178C environments.   Literature does not seem to be very clear where the actual where Java "includes relocation information in addition to the processor instruction information.”

Comment: I think the following is getting closer to explaining where the actual "processor instructions" are added: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15058/underst_jit.htm

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the bytecode *is* the processor instruction information.

The platform specific instructions aren't part of the bytecode. The JVM goes through the .class file and does different things depending on what bytecode instruction it is currently looking at (it is acting as a virtual CPU, hence the terminology of *virtual machine*). This is of course a simplification but you can think of the JVM as a massive switch statement. Some JVMs will analyse several bytecode instructions (an entire method perhaps) to produce some platform specific machine code that is executed by the CPU directly when needed (JIT Compilation).

Comment: You sure?  I see this as the definition of virtual machine: "A Java virtual machine (JVM), an implementation of the Java Virtual Machine Specification, interprets compiled Java binary code (called bytecode) for a computer's processor (or "hardware platform") so that it can perform a Java program's instructions." Reference: http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/Java-virtual-machine

Comment: @JustADude A virtual machine executes the bytecode, which are the instructions.

Comment: I'm looking for when the HW specific instructions are added.  Those get stuck in the object code by the compiler.  For Java looks like those processor instructions are added by the JVM during JIT type processes. "JIT compilation of the byte code into native machine code has to occur before a method executes"

Comment: @JustADude The platform specific instructions aren't part of the bytecode. The JVM goes through the .class file and does different things depending on what bytecode instruction it is currently looking at. This is of course a simplification but you can think of the JVM as a massive switch statement. Some JVMs will analyse several bytecode instructions (an entire method perhaps) to produce some platform specific machine code that is executed by the CPU directly when needed (JIT Compilation).

Comment: Thank you for the update.  I'm a bit confused by your answer now.  Should the first sentence be revised or edited as well?  That is, should "Yes, the bytecode..." be removed?  Seems that your comment above confirms that it does not contain processor specific processor instructions, which are added by the JIT. Thanks again.

Comment: @JustADude It depends on your definition of "processor instruction information". If it is defined as the raw machine code that is executed be physical processor, then no, bytecode doesn't include it.

Comment: I believe that is their intent, i.e. "processor instruction information" = physical (target) processor instructions executable by the physical (target) processor.   I believe...but I'm searching for confirmation...but since this definition was originally targeted at C code development I'm assuming that's the case.

Comment: @JustADude To me, the word "information" is significant, as it implies that there is some sort of metadata that comes along with the instructions, and therefore isn't raw machine code. That may not be correct of course.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question of definitions over technical properties, but the answer would be yes. To begin, there are specialized processors that are designed at the gate level to parse and execute JVM bytecode (with some constraints). Even if the bytecode is not run on a physical processor but rather a JVM, the bytecode is the set of instructions for the JVM itself. However, this bytecode may later be converted to processor instructions run natively on the physical processor in use by way of JIT compilation/optimization.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  This answer also seems to differ a bit or not with the feedback from Barry Burd in Android for Dummies: "the virtual machine serves as an interpreter between the run-anywhere byte code and your device's own system."   Seems to me that would imply that the specific "processor instruction information" is absent from the byte code.     I think the DO-178 definition is about the inclusion of the target HW instructions being included or not...maybe...

Comment: @JustADude There are physical processors that execute Java byte codes directly. Their instruction set is the JVM instruction set, but they aren't virtual, they are real. So are you asking about an extrinsic property? Because then of the course the answer will be it depends.

Comment: @erickson My understanding is that the JVM is an abstraction of the actual HW/OS and thus the bytecode itself contains no specific processor instruction information, and that the JVM adds in processor specific information.

Comment: @erickson  I'm trying to figure out when the processor specific instructions for the various platforms are actually added.  I understand kind of how it works for traditional object code and it looks like the JIT is adding that detail after processing down the byte code.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15058/underst_jit.htm